# Multiple Gmail notifications

Tags: notifications, gmail

Every time I get an email message in Gmail, the notification bar shows me 3 notifications instead of one: the first labeled important, the second labeled priority inbox, and the third is the regular one. How do I get only one notification and make my incoming mail regular/normal, without the auto-label important or priority?