# gmail label notification is overlapped by general one

Tags: notifications, gmail

I have set up notification by label on gmail app. Label notification is working but simultaneously with general gmail notification.

When message comes to target label:

First runs label notification, then in 1 second starts general notification. And general sound overlap label notification. So I almost don't hear label notification because it is too short. And I see 2 notifications in android notification bar: both for the same email.

How to set it up to run only one sound notification?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/45071/12442

Comment: thank you, Dan, sorry, that question about turning off label notification. If I turn it off, of course I will have only one notification, but it will be the same for all labels. The purpose is to get distinct sound for very important messages, for which I must react as fast as possible